# Nested MVVM with locator

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, mvvm, mvvm-light

I´m working on a WP7 application.-

**Summary**
I want to show a page (1) with a list of friends, if a friend is tapped i´ll show a page (2) with this friend info plus a list of movies this friend have watched. Then if I tap on one the movies I´ll get a page (3) with the movie info. I´m trying to use the MVVM patter with MVVM Light Toolkit.

**The service**:
*On every page I'll need to make a call to an API*
Page 1: `/friend`   return a list of friends
Page 2: `/friend/5436` return the movies watched by this friend
Page 3: `/movie/87968` return info about the movie

**What I did**
I create a friend class that has a ObservableCollection of Movies

```
public class Friend: ObservableObject
{
    public Friend(){}
    public ObservableCollection<Movie> Movies{ get; set; }
}
```

Also create a Movie class with the info of the movie.

Also a view model to wrap the Friend Class

```
public class FriendViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public Friend Model
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public FriendViewModel(Friend model)
    {
         Model = model
    }
}
```

Then a viewmodel to get all the friends

```
public class FriendListViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

    // To store the Friend service returned by the locator
    private readonly IFriendService _friendService;

    // To store the friends. It should be bind the the listbox in the view
    public ObservableCollection<FriendViewModel> Friends
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the FriendListViewModel class.
    /// </summary>
    public FriendListViewModel(IFriendService friendService)
    {
        // The data service
        _friendService = friendService;

        // Get all the friends and add them to the Friends collection
        Friends = new ObservableCollection<FriendViewModel>();
        _friendService.GetFriends((result, error) =>
        {
            if (error != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
                return;
            }

            if (result == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Nothing found");
                return;
            }

            foreach (var friend in friends)
            {
                Friends.Add(new FriendViewModel(friend));
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Every thing work with a locator that is a static resource on the App.xaml and the used in the view where I list the friends as the datacontext for the view
This is the locator

```
public class FriendViewModelLocator
{
    static FriendViewModelLocator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

        if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
        {
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IFriendService, Design.DesignFriendDataService>();

        }
        else
        {
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IFriendService, FriendService>();
        }

        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<FriendListViewModel>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the Main property.
    /// </summary>
    public FriendListViewModel FriendList
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<FriendListViewModel>();
        }
    }
}
```

**The Question**
The first page is working, i get the list of friends and i can display them. Also the first page is blendable. But then I don't know how to proceed with the next pages. I thought that I should pass the same `FriendViewModel` I tapped to the page 2 and call the the api to get the list of movies. But in some way it is disconected from the Friend model, I cannot fill the Movies collection on Friend. Should I create different viewmodels wrappers for each page. How to configure the locator to be able to get the movies and the movie info for the page 3.

any ideas, thoughts, resources to check?

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

- Have you view model as a property of your application so that it is accessible from every page in your application.
- Make your view model reflect the structure of the data, i.e. the `PersonViewModel` having a relationship to a collection of `MovieViewModels` which then returns the movie info.
- When navigating from page to page, pass a querystring that allows the next page to locate the item within the view model that should be used for its `DataContext`. For example, when a movie is clicked on, navigate to `MovieView.xaml?id=567` where 567 identifies the movie. You can then locate the movie in the `NavigatedTo` method, and set as `DataContext`.

This pattern will also help you tombstone your application, read more in my blog post [A Simple WP7 MVVM tombstoning example](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/05/a-simple-windows-phone-7-mvvm-tombstoning-example/).

Comment: I read yout blogpost, I don't quite understand how the model play it's part in the _"scene"_, I have the idea that you don't have a model, but the patter is MVVM..

Comment: The view model interacts with your service layer to retrieve model instances. The view and view model interaction is the same regardless.

Comment: @blackjid in the blog post I linked to the model is the XML data returned from the Twitter search.